# Given a RV as a function of another RV, prove the following conditional expectation equation almost surely holds

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Suppose a RV X is a function of a RV Y, X=f(Y) for some function f. Show that E[XZ|Y]=XE[Z|Y] almost surely for any RV Z

Not sure how to go about doing this, or doing almost surely proofs in general.

Comment: The RHS satisfies the two defining properties of the conditional expectation on the LHS (which surely you know?) hence LHS=RHS almost surely. (And anyway, conditional expectations can only be defined almost surely.)

Comment: right, but how would you go about proving it

Comment: I just did. Which part is not clear?

Comment: fair enough, it is a fairly trivial proof. I was just brainfarting, thanks!